# Receiving serial port data: real-time web display + logging (with downsampling)

Tags: php, python, mysql, logging, serial-port

I am working on a small project which involves displaying and recording (for later processing) data received through a serial port connection from some sort of measurement device. I am using a Raspberry Pi to read and store the received information: this is done with a small program written in Python which opens the serial device, reads a frame and stores the data in a MySQL database (there is no need to poll or interact with the device, data is sent automatically).

The serial data is formatted into frames about 2.5kbits long, which are sent repeatedly at 1200baud, which means that a new frame is received about every 2 seconds.

Now, even though the useful data is just a portion of the frame, that is way too much information to store for what I need, so what I'm currently doing is "downsampling" the data by reading a frame only once per minute. Currently this is done via a cron task which calls my logging script every minute.

The problem with my setup is that the PHP webpage used to display (and process) the received data (pulled from the MySQL database) cannot show new data more than once per minute.

Thus here come my question:

> **How would you do to make the webpage show the live data (which doesn't need to be saved), while keeping the logging to the MySQL database @ once per minute?**

I guess the solution would involve some sort of daemon, which stores the data at the specified frequency (once per minute), while keeping the latest received data available for the php webpage (how?). What do you think? Do you have any examples of similar code/applications which I could use as a starting point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but it appears you want to show a non-stop “stream” of data with your PHP script. If that's the case, I'm afraid this won't be so easy.

The basic idea of the HTTP protocol is request/response based. Your browser sends a request and receives a (static) response.

You could build some sort of “streaming” server, but streaming (such as done by youtube.com) is also not much more than periodically sending static chunks of a video file, and the player re-assembles them into a video or audio “stream”.

You could, however, look into concepts like “web sockets” and “long polling”. For example, you could create a long-running PHP script that reads a certail file once every two seconds and outputs the value. (Remember to use `flush()`, or output will be buffered.)

A smart solution could even output a JavaScript snippet every two seconds, which again would update some sort of `<div>` container displaying charts and what not.

There are for example implementations of progress meters implemented with this type of approach.